# How do I filter a part of sentence before and after a specific character using regex an loop

Tags: python, regex

'I want to extract the text before & after ":" and "|" using regex and seperate it into speaker and title.

### 'There are many such sentences so I need to write a loop'

```
 text1='If I controlled the internet | Rives '
 text2='Life at 30,000 feet | Richard Brandson'
 text3='larry brilliant : A surprising idea for "solving" climate change'
```

Comment: Literally sounds like you want to use `re.split('[\s]*[|:&][\s]*', text)`

Comment: @FailSafe I think OP means `before and after` - so you don't need `&`

Comment: @furas LOL. OMG, the antiquated usage of "&" lol. It has been a long time since I've seen that appear in a regular English sentence, especially when one is trying to split on symbols. Too funny. Whelp can't edit it right now, but will wait until OP returns to repost I guess (many posters ask a question, the disappear)

Comment: @FailSafe first I also thought OP want to split on `&` but later I saw answer below without `&`

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use plain string functions instead of regex:

```
if '|' in text:
    title, speaker = text.split('|', 1)
elif ':' in text:
    speaker, title = text.split(':', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex

```
re.compile('[\s]*[|:][\s]*').split(text)
```

Comment: I think OP means `before and after` - so you don't need `&`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple regex `'.[:|].'`,

```
import re
text1='If I controlled the internet | Rives '
text2='Life at 30,000 feet | Richard Brandson'
text3='larry brilliant : A surprising idea for "solving" climate change'

text = (text1, text2, text3)

for item in text:
    title, speaker = re.split('.[:|].', item)
    print('title:', title, ' - Speaker:', speaker)
```

output:

```
title: If I controlled the internet  - Speaker: Rives 
title: Life at 30,000 feet  - Speaker: Richard Brandson
title: larry brilliant  - Speaker: A surprising idea for "solving" climate change
```

note the last one :)